# C# lower the price with get/set if the value is over x

Tags: c#, properties, get, set

I need to use get and set commands to lower the price 10% if it's over 30. The price doesn't change and obviously there's something that I don't notice. The task requires to use property. Get must return price command's value. There was a tip to use if in set command.

```
using System;
class Book
{
public string Name;
public string Writer;
public string publisher;
private float price;
public string genre;



public Book(string Name, string Writer, string publisher, float price, string genre)
{
    this.Name = Name;
    this.Writer = Writer;
    this.publisher = publisher;
    this.price = price;
    this.genre = genre;
}    

public float Price
{
    get
    {
        return price;
    }
    set
    {
        if (value > 30)
        {
            price = value *0.90f;                
        }
        else
        {
            price = value;
        }
    }
}
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Book b = new Book("First Book", "W. Writer", "publish company 1", 21.50f, "Crime");
    Book b2 = new Book("Second Book", "T. Typer", "publish company 2", 36.90f, "Fantasy");
    Console.WriteLine(b.price);
    Console.WriteLine(b2.Price);
}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your constructor. Instead of accessing the price through the property, you access it directly. You class needs a small refactoring.

```
class Book
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Writer { get; set; }
    public string Publisher { get; set; }
    public string Genre { get; set; }

    private float _price;
    public float Price
    {
        get
        {
            return _price;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value > 30)
            {
                _price = value * 0.90f;
            }
            else
            {
                _price = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public Book(string name, string writer, string publisher, float price, string genre)
    {
        Name = name;
        Writer = writer;
        Publisher = publisher;
        Price = price;
        Genre = genre;
    }
}
```

It's a good practice to not exposing directly the field of a class. You can do so by using properties, which promotes the concept of encapsulation. What's the difference between the following property:

```
public string Name { get; set; }
```

and the property called `Price`. The first one is an auto implemented property. That means, when the code will be compiled, a backing field for the Name would be created and at the runtime the value of this field would be returned, when you access it (`book.Name`, where `book` is an instance of `Book`). It is equivalent to the following:

```
private string _name;
public string Name
{
    get { return _name;}
    set { _name = value; }
}
```

Furthermore, keep in mind the naming conventions we used above since this is common to many C# code bases. The properties start with a capital letter, while the private fields, start with a small letter (using always camel case) which sometimes is prefixed with an underscore, `_`.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it's never set because you never set a new price and your constructor is only set the price tag, not the property.

If you add`b2.Price = 36.90f;`

before your Console.Writeline it will set the correct value.

If you want to remove 10 percent in the constructor, then replace the line

```
this.price = price;
```

with

```
this.Price = price;
```

Also I suggest you should refactor your code a little. :)

Answer (score 0):

In main function you're instantiating the Book object with constructor and in constructor you set the price field, not property. So, the code you wrote for setting the price field never get executed. You can change the constructor to set the property not field ( that is `Price` with capital P )

```
this.Price = price;
```